# Cant read Email Message object fields in flow after Email to case

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email2case

I have email to case set up in my org,

The request is to forward this email to another mailbox after the case is created (based on related account criteria)

My issue is that I cannot get the values from the email message to forward this information on.

If I debug the flow once the case is created it says the data is there, but the email is blank,
not sure where I am going wrong, the case is created and Subject, body and email fields are populated on the case and usable. unfortunately I would like the CC field that is not included out of the box.

Any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At a quick glance, `TextBody` vs `Body` is something to look into

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from your screen grab if these actions are run immediately or not, but I think reading the email will only be possible on a run asynchronously path. I have had similar issues accessing email information from an email-to-case related email when using the run immediately path. Salesforce support advised me to switch to running asynchronously which resolved the problem.

Essentially, the actions to create the case and then link the email to the case need to happen before your flow actions run.